# Reference Column throwing error in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

User entity has OneToMany mapping with UserRole entity i.e 1 user can have many Role ids .
I am getting the below error : -

> Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find
>   column with logical name: USER_ID in
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Table(t_users) and its related supertables and
>   secondary tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_USERS")
public class User {

    @Column(name="ID_COL")
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="s")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME ")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="USER_EMAIL")
    private String userEmail;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;


    @Column(name="IS_ACTIVE")
    private Integer isActive;


    @OneToMany
      @JoinColumns(
                {
                  @JoinColumn(updatable=false,insertable=false, name="ID_COL", referencedColumnName="USER_ID"),
                }
                )
     private List<UserRole> userRole ;

// removed getters n setters for brevity
}

@Entity
@Table(name="T_MAP_USER_ROLES")
public class UserRole {

    @Column(name="MAP_ID")
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_user_role")
    private Integer mapId;

    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name="ROLE_ID ")
    private Integer roleId;

    @Column(name="IS_ACTIVE")
    private Integer isActive;

      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumns(
                {
                  @JoinColumn(updatable=false,insertable=false, name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ROLE_ID"),
                }
                )
       private Role  role;
```

What is the cause of the issue and how can I resolve it?
 the mapping between UserRole and Role entity is working fine

Answer (score 0):

@JoinColumns is only used for composite foreign keys. In this case, you just need @JoinColumn:

@OneToMany @JoinColumn(updatable=false,insertable=false, name="ID_COL")

Also, please note that you don't need "referencedColumnName" for single column foreign keys.